# Iterate through selective cells in a table row JavaScript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been having this issue which I haven't quite been able to solve through other given solutions.

I am trying to get certain values of each row in a table. 
The issue is coming from a fairly unformatted table, so I have to get cell values based on their index or location.

This is the table in question:

```
<table width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Item Description</td>
            <td>Colour</td>
            <td>Size</td>
            <td class="text-right">Price</td>
            <td class="text-right">Qty</td>
            <td class="text-right">Total</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="row_24551">
            <td width="40%">Item 1</td>
            <td>Ivory</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td class="text-right">$ 19.00</td>
            <td class="text-right">1</td>
            <td class="text-right">$ 19.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row_24550">
            <td width="40%">Item 2</td>
            <td>Grey Marle</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td class="text-right">$ 18.95</td>
            <td class="text-right">1</td>
            <td class="text-right">$ 18.95</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have been getting the row values with

`var table = $('tr[id^="row"]')`
As the information needed is in the rows with an ID.

Can output each cells contents with

```
var table = $('tr[id^="row"]');
table.each(function(){
    console.log('row');
    $.each(this.cells, function(){
        console.log($(this).text());
    });
});
```

Where I'm getting stuck is that I only want cells [0,2,4,5] and I'm not sure how to be selective through the .each function.

For loops make a bit more sense to me when being selective but I haven't been able to get an iteration of cells via the rows:

```
var table = $('tr[id^="row"]');
for(i = 0; i < table.length; i++) { 
    console.log("row");
}
```

Also tried this

```
var table = $('tr[id^="row"]');
for(var i = 0, row; row = table[i]; i++) { 
    console.log("row");
    for (var j = 0, col; col = row[j]; j++) {
        console.log("cell");
    }  
}
```

But the cells values don't seem to come through.

Ultimately looking to push each of the cell values needed ( [0,2,4,5] ) into a product array which will map {name, size, quantity, price}. But help with the cells would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the cell's index like this :

```
var table = $('tr[id^="row"]')
var tabCells = {0: "name", 2: "size", 4: "quantity", 5: "price"} //These are the names of the needed cells
var tabRows = []; //This will store the rows data
table.each(function(){
    var tabRow = {}; //This will store the current row data
    $.each(this.cells, function(index){
      if($.inArray(index, [0,2,4,5]) > -1)
        tabRow[tabCells[index]] = $(this).text();
        //e.g: tabRow[tabCells[0]] => tabRow["name"]
    })
    tabRows.push(tabRow);
})
```

Comment: This seems really close to what I need, is there a way to push each cell (from the index) value into a new array?

I tried adding in `products.push(` where the `console.log('row')` is but it ends up pushing in every td instead of the text values.

Comment: If I do something like this, its also a step closer

`var table = $('tr[id^="row"]');
var products = [];
table.each(function(){
    
    $.each(this.cells, function(index){
      if($.inArray(index, [0,2,4,5]) > -1)
       products.push( $(this).text() );
    })
})`
But there is information for 2 products in one array, when really what I would like is this output:

`// [{name: "Item 1", size: "10", quantity: "1", price: "$ 19.00"},
// {name: "Item 2", size: "10", quantity: "1", price: "$ 18.95"}]`
Would that be possible?

Comment: It is also apparent that while I browse StackOverflow a lot I do not know how to format comments properly. Sorry!

Comment: Thanks @Hamza,

This worked great, I had to put a few more edits in for some final values in a couple of the cells but got it working! This will help me a lot in the future!

Answer (score 0):

try cellIndex:

```
var table = $('tr[id^="row"]');
table.each(function() {
    $.each(this.cells, function() {
        if ([0, 2, 4, 5].indexOf(this.cellIndex) > -1) {
            console.log($(this).text());
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using only JavaScript. If you need to support for older browsers, then i can rewrite it.

```
var rows = document.querySelectorAll('tr[id^="row"]');

//const rowArray = Array.from(rows);
var rowArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(rows);

var products = rowArray.reduce((sum, element) => {
    var children = element.children;
    var name = children[0].innerHTML;
    var size = children[2].innerHTML;
    var quantity = children[4].innerHTML;
    var prize = children[5].innerHTML;
    var newElement = {name: name, size: size, quantity: quantity, prize: prize};
    sum.push(newElement);
    return sum;
},[]);

console.log(products);
// [{name: "Item 1", size: "10", quantity: "1", prize: "$ 19.00"},
// {name: "Item 2", size: "10", quantity: "1", prize: "$ 18.95"}]
```

Comment: Hi Pavlo, 

this was outputting nicely in the console but when running it on site I have this error:

this language feature is only supported for ECMASCRIPT6 mode or better: const declaration. Use --language_in=ECMASCRIPT6 or ECMASCRIPT6_STRICT or higher to enable ES6 features.

Is this the browser issue you mentioned?

Comment: Updated it so it doesn't use ES6 features, and yes partially. If there are more errors, then look to change `querySelectorAll` or `rowArray.reduce`, but it shouldn't happen

Comment: Thanks @Pavlo! 
I will be saving this for a JS alternative! Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Taking advantage of pure JavaScript, though this does require a relatively up-to-date browser, I'd like to suggest the following approach:

```
function collateDataByIndices(opts) {
  // settings, used to define some defaults for the function,
  // passing in the opts Object allows those defaults to be
  // overridden.


  // 'table':              DOM Node, HTMLTableElement,
  // 'indices :            Array of numbers, the indices of which
  //                       cells from which you wish to obtain data,
  // 'rowIndexStartAt :    Number, the rowIndex at which you
  //                       wish to start collecting data.
  // 'tableHeadRowIndex' : the row index of the column
  //                       headings,
  // 'namedByTable':       Uses the table's column headings
  //                       to identify the data in the returned
  //                       Array of Objects,
  // 'keys':               Array of Strings, if you wish to use
  //                       different keys to identify the data
  //                       in the returned Array of Objects.
  let settings = {
    'table': document.querySelector('table'),
    'indices': null,
    'rowIndexStartAt': 1,
    'tableHeadRowIndex': 0,
    'namedByTable': true,
    'keys': false
  };

  // here we use the Object.keys() method to retrieve an array
  // of the keys from the supplied 'opts' Object (or an empty
  // Object, to avoid errors being thrown if 'opts' is not supplied):
  Object.keys(opts || {}).forEach(

    // we then use Array.prototype.forEach() to iterate over each
    // key of the opts Object (if supplied), and update the
    // settings Object so that supplied options override the
    // defaults:
    key => settings[key] = opts[key]
  );

  // if we have no indices supplied, or the length of the supplied
  // Array of indices is 0 (although '!settings.indices.length'
  // would also work, as 0 is a falsey value):
  if (!settings.indices || settings.indices.length === 0) {

    // we retrieve the cells of the HTMLTableElement's first
    // row, and use Array.from() to convert that HTMLCollection
    // into an Array (note this is a naive check, since cells
    // that use a `colspan` attribute may cause inaccurate cell
    // counts ('columns') to be retrieved):
    settings.indices = Array.from(
      settings.table.rows[0].cells

    // we then use Array.prototype.map(), along with an Arrow
    // function:
    ).map(

      // here we pass both 'cell' (the current cell of the
      // Array of cells over which we're iterating) and the
      // 'index' of that cell in the Array to the function,
      // and simply return the index to create an Array of
      // all indices (there is almost certainly a better way
      // to do this):
      (cell, index) => index
    );
  }

  // here we retrieve the <tr> elements, using document.querySelectorAll(),
  // and use Array.from() to convert that NodeList into an Array of element
  // nodes:
  let rows = Array.from(
      settings.table.querySelectorAll('tr')

    // we then slice that collection from the supplied, or default,
    // settings.rowIndexStartAt to retrieve the relevant subset of
    // rows (note that this remains naive, since there's no check
    // that such an argument is supplied or available):
    ).slice(
      settings.rowIndexStartAt

    // we then use Array.prototype.map() on the Array returned from
    // Array.prototype.slice():
    ).map(

      // here we pass 'row' (the current HTMLTableRowElement of the
      // Array of HTMLTableRowElement nodes over which we're iterating)
      // to the Arrow function; in which create an Array of that row's
      // children (child elements) and filter that collection of children
      // using Array.prototype.filter():
      row => Array.from(row.children).filter(

        // here we pass both 'cell' (the current cell of the Array of
        // cells), and the'index' of that cell from the collection;
        // we then use Array.prototype.indexOf() to determine if the
        // current cell's index is in the Array of indices we wish to
        // keep. Array.prototype.indexOf() returns the index of the
        // supplied value if it was found, and -1 if it was not found;
        // therefore any returned index greater than -1 means the
        // supplied value was found, and should be kept in the filtered
        // Array:
        (cell, index) => settings.indices.indexOf(index) > -1
      )
    ),
    keyNames, headingSource, headings;

  // if an Array of keys were supplied, in order to assign custom
  // keys/names to identify the retrieved values/data:
  if (settings.keys && settings.keys.length > 0) {

    // keyNames is equal to the supplied keys:
    keyNames = settings.keys;

  // otherwise, if settings.namedByTable is (Boolean) true:
  } else if (settings.namedByTable === true) {

    // ...and settings.tableHeadRowIndex, parsed as a base-ten
    // integer, is equal-to or greater-than zero (zero is itself
    // a falsey value, so must be explicitly tested for):
    if (parseInt(settings.tableHeadRowIndex, 10) >= 0) {

      // we retrieve the settings.table HTMLTableElement:
      headingSource = settings.table
        // and retrieve the HTMLTableRowElement at the
        // index supplied in the settings.tableHeadRowIndex
        // argument:
        .rows[ settings.tableHeadRowIndex ]
        // and retrieve its child elements:
        .children;

    // otherwise, if the HTMLTableElement has a non-zero number of
    // <th> elements within a <thead> element:
    } else if (settings.table.querySelectorAll('thead th').length) {

      // we retrieve those elements:
      headingSource = settings.table.querySelectorAll('thead th')

    // otherwise, if the HTMLTableElement has a non-zero number of
    // <td> elements within a <thead> element:
    } else if (settings.table.querySelectorAll('thead td').length) {

      // we retrieve those elements:
      headingSource = settings.table.querySelectorAll('thead td')

    // otherwise, if the parsed integer of settings.rowIndexStartAt
    // in base-ten, is greater than zero:
    } else if (parseInt(settings.rowIndexStartAt, 10) > 0) {

      // we retrieve the HTMLTableRowElement at the index before the
      // the settings.rowIndexStartAt variable:
      headingSource = settings.table.rows[
        settings.rowIndexStartAt - 1 
      // and retrieve its child elements:
      ].children;
    }

    // here we convert the array-like headingSource variable
    // into an explicit Array (using Array.from):
    keyNames = Array.from(headingSource)
      // and then use Array.prototype.filter() to filter that
      // Array using an Arrow function:
      .filter(
        // here we do as we did earlier, and retain only those
        // elements whose index is found in the settings.indices
        // Array:
        (header, index) => settings.indices.indexOf(index) > -1

    // we then use Array.prototype.map() on the filtered Array:
    ).map(

      // and modify the Array to contain the trimmed text-content
      // of each cell:
      header => header.textContent.trim()
    )

  // otherwise:
  } else {

    // we simply use the numeric indices (if names cannot be found,
    // or appear to be unwanted):
    keyNames = settings.indices;
  }

  // here we iterate over the Array of HTMLTableRowElements:
  return rows.map(

    // pass the current row of the Array of rows:
           // here we reduce the current HTMLTableRowElement
           // and convert that array-like collection into an
           // Array:
    row => Array.from(row)

      // reducing the Array in order to convert it to an Object:
      .reduce(function(accumulator, current, index) {
        // the accumulator is the Object literal supplied after
        // this anonymous function; and we set the key to identify
        // the current value (from the keyNames Array) to be the
        // key located at the same index as the current cell; and
        // we supply the textContent of the current cell as the
        // value associated with that key:
        accumulator[keyNames[index]] = current.textContent;

      // here we return the accumulator:
      return accumulator;
    }, {})
  );
}

let found = collateDataByIndices({
  indices: [0, 2, 4, 5]
});

console.log(found);
```

```js
function collateDataByIndices(opts) {
  let settings = {
    'table': document.querySelector('table'),
    'indices': null,
    'rowIndexStartAt': 1,
    'tableHeadRowIndex': 0,
    'namedByTable': true,
    'keys': false
  };

  Object.keys(opts || {}).forEach(
    key => settings[key] = opts[key]
  );

  if (!settings.indices || settings.indices.length === 0) {
    settings.indices = Array.from(
      settings.table.rows[0].cells
    ).map(
      (cell, index) => index
    );
  }

  let rows = Array.from(
      settings.table.querySelectorAll('tr')
    ).slice(
      settings.rowIndexStartAt
    ).map(
      row => Array.from(row.children).filter(
        (cell, index) => settings.indices.indexOf(index) > -1
      )
    ),
    keyNames, headingSource, headings;

  if (settings.keys && settings.keys.length > 0) {
    keyNames = settings.keys;
  } else if (settings.namedByTable === true) {
    if (parseInt(settings.tableHeadRowIndex, 10) >= 0) {
      headingSource = settings.table.rows[settings.tableHeadRowIndex].children
    } else if (settings.table.querySelectorAll('thead th').length) {
      headingSource = settings.table.querySelectorAll('thead th')
    } else if (settings.table.querySelectorAll('thead td').length) {
      headingSource = settings.table.querySelectorAll('thead td')
    } else if (parseInt(settings.rowIndexStartAt, 10) > 0) {
      headingSource = settings.table.rows[settings.rowIndexStartAt - 1].children;
    }

    keyNames = Array.from(headingSource).filter(
      (header, index) => settings.indices.indexOf(index) > -1
    ).map(
      header => header.textContent.trim()
    )

  } else {
    keyNames = settings.indices;
  }


  return rows.map(
    row => Array.from(row).reduce(function(accumulator, current, index) {
      accumulator[keyNames[index]] = current.textContent;
      return accumulator;
    }, {})
  );
}

let found = collateDataByIndices({
  indices: [0, 2, 4, 5]
});

console.log(found);
```

```html
<table width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Item Description</td>
      <td>Colour</td>
      <td>Size</td>
      <td class="text-right">Price</td>
      <td class="text-right">Qty</td>
      <td class="text-right">Total</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="row_24551">
      <td width="40%">Item 1</td>
      <td>Ivory</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td class="text-right">$ 19.00</td>
      <td class="text-right">1</td>
      <td class="text-right">$ 19.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row_24550">
      <td width="40%">Item 2</td>
      <td>Grey Marle</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td class="text-right">$ 18.95</td>
      <td class="text-right">1</td>
      <td class="text-right">$ 18.95</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/fuaqnayh/).

References:

- [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).
- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
- [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).
- [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
- [`HTMLTableElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement).
- [`HTMLTableRowElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement).
- [JavaScript Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [`Object.prototype.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).
- [`ParentNode.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children).
- [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Comment: This solution is great! But a bit too complex I think for what I am after. Output is great as well. I think I need to do a bit more of a deep dive into this construct, thanks